# How to do string functions on a db table column?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do string replace on entries of a column inside a db table. So far, I have reached till here:

```
$misa = DB::table('mis')->pluck('name');
for($i=0;;$i++)
{
    $misa[$i] = substr_replace("$misa[$i]","",-3);
}
```

The error I am getting is "Undefined offset:443".

P.S. I am not a full-fledged programmer. Only trying to develop a few simple programs for my business. Thank You.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you give examples of names you have and what the exact result you want to get?

Comment: These are product codes like socf:ut,  tis:ut.  I want to remove :ut from the end of all product codes.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a collection, use the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) collection method transform it and avoid this kind of errors. Also, you can just use [`str_before()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-before) method to transform each string:

```
$misa = DB::table('mis')->pluck('name');
$misa->transform(function($i) {
    return str_before($i, ':ut');
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Makes my work so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to make this query prettier and FASTER!  The beauty of Laravel is that we have the use of both Eloquent for pretty queries and then Collections to manage the data in a user friendly way. So, first lets clean up the query.  You can instead use a DB::Raw select and do all of the string replacing in the query itself like so:

```
$misa = DB::table('mis')->select(DB::raw("REPLACE(name, ':ut' , '') as name"));
```

Now, we have a collection containing only the name column, and you've removed ':ut' in your specific case and simply replaced it with an empty string all within the MySQL query itself.

Surprise! That's it.  No further php manipulation is required making this process much faster (will be noticeable in large data sets - trust me).

Cheers!